# is_home() like function for Custom Post Type of WordPress

Tags: wordpress, post

I am using a custom post type name **news**.

For this purpose, my files are:

```
archive-news.php
single-news.php
```

Now I need to trace that I am using news page for some sidebar content issues.

In Wordpress we have this:

```
is_home() 
is_single()
```

Is there a way to do like this?

```
is_news_home()
is_news_single()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `is_post_type_archive()` and `is_singular()` WP functions.

---

For the **archive-news.php**:

```
if (is_post_type_archive('news')) {
  /* code */
}
```

For the **single-news.php**:

```
if (is_singular('news')) {
  /* code */
}
```

Comment: @Aminul remember to mark this is the correct answer if it works for you :)